# Browser cache- not understanding the cache related headers

Tags: html, apache

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Age: 422816
Expires: Fri, 25 Jul 2014 20:52:54 GMT
Date: Thu, 25 Jul 2013 20:52:54 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 29 Mar 2012 18:19:50 GMT
```

What is the purpose of the max-age, age, date, and last modified headers if the browser can just use the expires: date to determine if something should be cached or refreshed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its mostly legacy, though some headers do subtly different things. Different browsers work differently (certainly in the past), and there wasn't always a standard way of doing things. Eg. IE 6 won't respond to modern caching headers. To make sure a site works correctly, we have to consider older browsers (at least for now).

Have a look [at this page](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/) for some good information.

Comment: So what is the most up to date one? If you just add a last-modified, do modern browsers just use that or? Is there a guide somewhere that tells you what precedence certain headers have over others?

Comment: I've added a link to the answer